# Does the word nightclub have any negative/shady connotation with strip clubs and gentlemen's bars?

Tags: meaning

[Nightclub](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nightclub), from MW:

> A place of entertainment open at night usually serving food and liquor and providing music and space for dancing and often having a floor show.

I am curious if there is any part of the English speaking world where a casual sentence, like: *I am heading to a nightclub now.* is/should be understood, as *I am heading to a shady place to spend a ton of money on ridiculously overpriced alcohol, strip girls, and/or hookers.*

Is the difference between nightclub and strip club/gentlemen's club chrsytal clear at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can give an exhaustive answer, as you are requesting.  However, I can say that in the U.S. I have never seen *nightclub* have this connotation.  I have been to nightclubs on the East Coast, West Coast, and points in between.

Comment: Is there any way to make this answer authoritative? I am thinking of looking up the frequencies of "nightclub" and "hookers", "lap dance" or whatever in the same context; and this should be compared to "gentleman's bar" and "hookers", "lap dance" or whatever. How would one do research of this kind? Let's say, it's your topic of your MA thesis.

Comment: Oh, well if it's your thesis, then you get to collect data at nightclubs.  I hope you like to dance!

Comment: There is a difference between *nightclub* and "*nightclub*", if you catch my drift.